# Зачем нужна константа VG_ACCESS?

Tags: php

Зачем нужна конструкция `defined("VG_ACCESS") or die ("access denied");`? От чего она защищает?

Comment: Насколько я могу судить по примерам кода на гитхабе — от попыток обращения напрямую к php-файлам, к которым напрямую обращаться не положено, в обход файла index.php. А в файле index.php соответственно пишут строчку `define('VG_ACCESS', true)`